# Tomcat context.xml from META-INF folder for context root configuration

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat8

I have an application which is being deployed in Tomcat 8. This application needs to be the context root.

To do this, I put a root.xml file in conf\Catalina\localhost folder and it worked.

Now, the problem is that when i debug through IntelliJ idea (Remote host) it is not being deployed as the root application.

Seems like the only way to fix this problem is to add context.xml file in META-INF folder and specify the configuration there.

Now, when I do this, context root configuration from context.xml file is not being picked up.

Any thoughts on this? Ultimately, I just need to debug the application through a remote server.